# After connecting to BLE device,how can i know which services are available, i only know to print uuids but i want to know the name of service

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

i am new to android development with Kotlin, i am developing an app to search for BLE devices.
i am able to print the services(uuids) and its characterstics(uuids). i dont have any particular beacon to connect. i am just searching with my app and getting list of ble devices around me.
i am randomly connecting to one of them and printing its services to the console. My question is that how can i know for the device i am connecting what it is advertising and what can i read from it.
i am not getting any idea from these uuids.
please tell me if you need more information regarding this.

```
printGattTable: Service 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristics:
    |--00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Service d0611e78-bbb4-4591-a5f8-487910ae4366
    Characteristics:
    |--8667556c-9a37-4c91-84ed-54ee27d90049
    Service 9fa480e0-4967-4542-9390-d343dc5d04ae
    Characteristics:
    |--af0badb1-5b99-43cd-917a-a77bc549e3cc
    Service 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristics:
    |--00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Service 00001805-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristics:
    |--00002a2b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    |--00002a0f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34f
```

Comment: `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getName()` Something like this ?

Comment: Yes, but i want to know the names of services available for a ble device.

Answer (score 7):

There is no predefined method to convert UUIDs to their respective service name. You would have to write it yourself. You can find a list of assigned 16-bit UUIDs containing the Bluetooth SIG member UUIDs and the GATT Service UUIDs [here](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf).
There are also some projects on Github that provide an easy to parse UUID list like the [bluetooth-numbers-database](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/bluetooth-numbers-database/blob/master/v1/service_uuids.json).

Keep in mind that a device can also 'hide' its services behind non standard UUIDs, even if they use a standard GATT service. You won't be able to tell what the service is doing in that case unless you find a description in that devices documentation.

Answer (score 1):

On the protocol level there is no such thing as a Service Name. There is only UUID. Therefore what you want to do is impossible. You can try to search online for a mapping from UUID to service names for common services and embed that into your app.